# Implementation of Red-Black Tree in C#

Tags: c#, red-black-tree

I'm looking for an implementation of a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) in C#, with the following features:

- Search, Insert and Delete in O(log n).
- Members type should be generic.
- Support in [Comparer(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx), for sorting `T` by different fields in it.
- Searching in the tree should be with the specific field, so it won't accept `T`, but it'll accept the field type sorting it.
- Searching shouldn't be only exact value. Should support searching the lower/higher one.

Thank you.

Comment: Answering to your other question, named "Book or Teacher", the *really* best way to learn programming is to *write programs*.  Write this one on your own and then you'll learn something.

Comment: @Pavel: I could write this, but I'm looking for something ready, so I can continue develop the main sides of my program, and speed up development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mostly just described [`SortedDictionary<T, U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx), except for the next-lowest/next-highest value binary search, which you could implement on your own without much difficulty.

Are there specific reasons that `SortedDictionary` is insufficient for you?

Comment: *"which you could implement on your own without much difficulty."* I don't believe you can easily extend SortedDictionary. From looking at the metadata, and simply trying to extend it, the internal pieces necessary do not seem to be accessible. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the SortedDictionary<T, U> implements a Red-Black Tree? If you do, where did you find this? I don't see any mention of it on the MSDN pages.

Comment: Yes; I just verified it by skimming the class in Reflector.  Internally, it puts the keys into a `SortedSet<T>`, which is implemented as a red/black tree.  I'm not sure where I heard about it -- I feel like an old version of the MSDN documentation went into more detail about the implementation of `SortedDictionary` in contrast to `SortedList`.  Also, umm, I'm not exactly sure why I thought he could easily extend it.  It isn't clear that he could.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Rip the TreeSet from C5 collection libs.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the OrderedDictionary in PowerCollections.  It's pretty much identical to SortedDictionary (red black tree with generics) with the addition of the ability to set a start key/end key and scan all values in that range.

SortedDicionary only allows exposes a GetEnumerator() function that starts at the beginning of the collection and only allows a MoveNext() call, so even if you use LINQ there is nothing magic happening: it starts at the beginning and runs your expression on every single node, in order, until it finds those matching your LINQ expression.

OrderedDictionary has a function that gets an enumerator at or before a particular key and that does the lookup in O(log n).

A word of caution though: the enumerator in the PowerCollections OrderedDictionary is implemented using "yield" and the memory usage and enumeration performance is at least O(n^2)... you can change the implementation yourself to make it implement a traditional enumerator and both of these problems go away.  I'll submit that patch to Codeplex if I can ever find the time.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=net-7.0) is implemented as a red-black tree.